# High Trust on Provider-Hosted app and clientContext

Tags: 2013, development, csom, 2016, high-trust-app

Ok a while back I thought my application was kinda 'at odds' with what SharePoint could do at the box. So started using `ClientContext` and webservices to do what I wanted.

I used the MVC framework and before I knew it I was off and happy.

This was in the days of SharePoint 2010 and seemed like the best thing todo.

Now we are going through a process of upgrading to SP2013 and then to SP2016

Both have the SharePoint add-in option, given the complexity of my application I can't use the javascript api and so that means I'm using the provider-hosted application.

From what I can tell the deployment installs a 'link' to sharepoint when clicked on sends the url (context) to the application so it can start.

The application however is still a csom MVC site the very same that I have created previously albeit I have to specify the site in a config.

Am I missing something do I gain something more with high-trust applications?
Is there some gain with some O-Auth in the background?
Can anyone point me at some high-trust application code where there is this gain?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer can be found here.
http://www.instantquick.com/index.php/high-trust-apps-and-low-trust-apps-what-does-it-all-mean?c=elumenotion-blog-archive/sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-apps

But the long and short of it is this the 'normal' way of doing csom is ClientContext(url) however this downside here is that the context will be whatever the app pool runs as.

This has problems when you check-in/out also it may have problems with permissions as all permissions are taken from the app pool user.

So enter high-trust applications. They are still csom and outside the realm of sharepoint however they can run either as the apppool or as any user (default the windows user - using windows authentication).

The permissions they have will be the same or lower than the app pool user.

They are tricky and need https to work properly but seems to be the way sharepoint is going for complicated csom projects.